# Passing a function and its parameters as a parameter to another

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've seen a few answers but its still a little unclear to me how to go about this.

I have a retry function, whose parameter of `fn` I'd like to call with the original parameters supplied to it:

```
function retry(fn, retries=3, err=null) {
  if (!retries) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
  return fn().catch(err => {
      return retry(fn, (retries - 1), err);
    });
}
```

Is there a clean way to do this in JS?

In short, I'd like to do something like:

```
function a(b,c,d) { return Promise.resolve(b + c + d) }

retry(a, ...originalParams)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Actually another way I found to do this (I think) is to pass an list as an argument containing all of the parameters, and then unpacking it with the spread operator. `retry(fn, args, retries = 3, err = null)` and then `retry(func, [1,2,3])`

Answer (score 0):

Besides what you've covered yourself, another way would be to wrap your function and it's arguments into a thunk. However, it's not exactly what you would like it to be.

```js
function retry(fn, retries=3, err=null) {
  if (!retries) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
  return fn().catch(err => {
      return retry(fn, (retries - 1), err);
    });
}

function toThunk(fn, ...args) {
  // note that we return a new function which closes over 
  // the function and arguments here (e. g. creating closures)
  return () => fn(...args);
}

function sumP(a, b, c) {
  return Promise.resolve(a + b + c);
}


// ---

retry(toThunk(sumP, 1, 2, 3)).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```